# Saving and loading iCalendar event data in a separate file

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable, icalendar

I am creating a program which can manage project schedule using iCalendar. I need to be able to save all the information used in creating a VEvent in some type of data holder and then output it in a file, which after can be loaded and data might be edited or more data added. I think JTable is kind of suitable for my needs, one row will represent one VEvent and columns will have different information. But if anyone has a better suggestion, I want to hear it.

My question is, what is the best data holder for this type of information and how to save that data to a file and load it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for sure use the iCalendar file format as defined in [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) and only have one VEVENT in your calendar and have a file per event but you could equally store them in a database and leverage this SO[ical-field-list-for-database-schema-based-on-ical-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054201/ical-field-list-for-database-schema-based-on-ical-standard)

Answer (score 0):

VEvent seems like a good idea since it´s easy to export to this format for your custumers.